# AWS CLI: Attach an existing cloudwatch alarm to an existing auto scaling policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm having trouble attaching previously created alarms to an auto scaling group policy.  I have created the policy like so:

```
aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --policy-name my-scaleout-policy --auto-scaling-group-name my-group --scaling-adjustment 2 --adjustment-type ChangeInCapacity
```

However, I can't seem to find the correct CLI command to attach an already created alarm `my-cpu-alarm` to the policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the existing alarm & add the policy ARN in `--alarm-actions` parameter.

You can use the [put-metric-alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html) command for this.
Note that you will have to give all the original parameters to update the alarm as they are overwritten.

You can get the alarm parameters using [describe-alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html).

Comment: is there a way to do this from the scaling template?